# Formatting an integer with irregular separators

Tags: php, number-formatting

With following php code i can get total amount of debit columns from Mysql Database:

***Php Code***

```
$total_debit = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(debit) FROM supplier_jv");
$re_t = mysql_fetch_array($total_debit);
$t_d =  $re_t['SUM(debit)'];
```

Suppose.. it's amount 590185.
So i want to show this amount like: **5,90,185** (should be a coma **(,)** after 3 integer first and then 2 integer )

How do i do this with php?

Comment: Why would you want to display it like that?  (As opposed to regular thousands separators.)

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated, please use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: Have you experimented with `sprintf()`?

Comment: If **123456** becomes **1,23,456** then what does **123456789** become? **12,34,56,789**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFormat($n) {
  if ($n < 0) return '-'.myFormat(-$n);

  $s = (string) $n;
  if (strlen($s) > 3) {
    $parts = array();
    $parts[] = substr($s, -3);
    if (strlen($s) > 5) {
      $parts[] = substr($s, -5, 2);
      $parts[] = substr($s, 0, strlen($s) - 5);
    }else{
      $parts[] = substr($s, 0, strlen($s) - 3);
    }
    return implode(',', array_reverse($parts));
  } else {
    return $s;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you wanted to write `if ($n < 0) return '-'.myFormat($n); 
`

Comment: Doesn't it cause an infinite loop now?

Answer (score 2):

Check the [number_format](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

Comment: **Correction:** You need to create your own function for an irregularly separated number.